# How to add target to Default context in ZAPapi using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, zap

So in the GUI, we could just select the target that we want to scan and include it in the default context for scans. How can this be done using the API?

Answer (score 1):

Per: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/api/#contextactionincludeincontext

If you wanted to, for example, include everything `example.com` in `Default Context`:

```py
import requests
headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'X-ZAP-API-Key': 'API_KEY'
}

r = requests.get('http://zap/JSON/context/action/includeInContext/', params={
  'contextName': 'Default Context',  'regex': 'http(s)?:\/\/example\.com.*'
}, headers = headers)

print r.json()
```

The regex is based on: https://regex101.com/r/PSkoBl/3

Comment: ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='zap', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /JSON/context/action/includeInContext/?contextName=Default+Context&regex=https%3A%2F%2Flive.qsome.tech%2Fapi%2Ftest-results%2F11%2F (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000016298CBBB48>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

Comment: Zap probably isn't listening on port 80

Comment: Okay I adjusted the settings but I get  `<Response [400]>` as a response.

Comment: Did you provide the apikey? Is the client on the allowed list?

Comment: Are you referring to the ZAP api key, because that's already in use to create the ZAP instance. As for the target I have the Authorization token, but I'm not sure how to use it in this context.